# Error in Postgresql : for creating language plpythonu

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

`Postgresql` is throwing error while creating language `plpythonu`

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib/plpython.dll": The specified module could not be found.
```

I have confirmed installation of `python 2.6.`The file `plpython.dll` is present in `lib folder` of `postgresql`.
I have also copied `plpython.dll` to `postgresql bin`.
but still getting same error

help required

Comment: And you are positive that the file `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib/plpython.dll` is there and can be accessed by the system user that's running the database?

Comment: The database user has read write permission on the postgresql folder

Comment: yes the database user is having read/write on postgresql folder

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this:

1:  Make sure that the user in question can read the library

2:  Make sure Python works properly for all users (try creating a new limited user and try to run Python).  Maybe it is failing to load because another library it is dependent on is failing?